# Proof by calculation binomial coefficient

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, binomial-coefficients

$m,n \in \mathbb{N}, m<n\\ k=0,...,m$

Proof by calculation:

$\frac{1}{m^k} \binom{m}{k} \leq \frac{1}{n^k} \binom{n}{k}$

---

$\frac{1}{m^k} \binom{m}{k} = \frac{m!}{m^k * k! * (m-k)!}$

$\frac{1}{n^k} \binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{n^k * k! * (n-k)!}$

If $k$ has its smallest value: $k=0$

$\Rightarrow \frac{m!}{m^0 * 0! * (m-0)!} = \frac{1}{1} = 1$

$\Rightarrow \frac{n!}{n^0 * 0! * (n-0)!} = \frac{1}{1} = 1$

If $k$ has its maximum value: $k=m$

$\Rightarrow \frac{m!}{m^m * m! * (m-m)!}= \frac{1}{m^m}$

$\Rightarrow \frac{n!}{n^m * m! * (n-m)!} =$

I got stuck here. I'm not sure whether going by different cases of $k$ is the right way.

Comment: Note that $$f(n) := \frac{1}{n^k} \binom{n}{k} = \frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}{n^k k!} = \frac{1}{k!}\prod_{j=0}^{k-1} \left( 1 - \frac{j}{n} \right). $$ Since each factor $n \mapsto 1-\frac{j}{n}$ is increasing in $n$ and are non-negative for $n \geq k$, it follows that $f(n)$ is increasing in $n \geq k$. This gives $$f(m) \leq f(n)$$ for $k \leq m \leq n$, proving the desired inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Show that $$\frac{n^k}{m^k} \leq \frac{\binom nk}{\binom mk}$$

and use that for $i=0,\ldots , m-1$ you have
$$\frac nm \leq \frac{n-i}{m-i} \Leftrightarrow m \leq n$$

Comment: So I came up til here:

$\frac{n^k}{m^k} \leq \frac{n! * (m-k)!}{m! * (n-k)!}\\ k=0: 1\leq 1 \\k=m: \frac{n^m}{m^m} \leq \frac{n!}{m!*(n-m)!}$ How do I continue?

Comment: @franz3 : 
You have $\binom nk = \frac{n(n-1) \cdots (n-k+1)}{k!}$.

So, $\frac{\binom nk}{\binom mk} = \frac{n(n-1) \cdots (n-k+1)}{m(m-1) \cdots (m-k+1)} = \underbrace{\frac nm \cdot \frac{n-1}{m-1}\cdots \frac{n-k+1}{m-k+1}}_{k\; factors}$. Each of the factors is greater than or equal to $\frac{n}{m}$.

Comment: @franz3 : Now, you consider the case $1 \leq k < m$. Write the fraction as I did in my previous comment. The only thing you need to know now is the inequality I wrote in my answer. You can show it just by multiplying the left inequality by $m(m-i)$ and then expanding the expressions. Just give it a try.

Comment: but $k$ was defined as $0 \leq k \leq m$. And how did you get to the inequality in your answer. Another question: If each of the factors is greater than or equal to $\frac{n}{m}$ how does that apply to $\frac{n^k}{m^k}$

Comment: @franz3 : 
You have $\frac{n^k}{m^k} = \left( \frac nm\right)^k = \underbrace{\frac nm \cdots \frac nm}_{k \; factors} $. For each of the factors you have $\frac nm \leq \frac{n-i}{m-i}$ for $i=0,\ldots , m-1$. So, on the left side there is a product of $k$ factors, on the right side is also a product of $k$ factors, but each factor on the right side is greater than or equal to any factor of the left side.

Comment: BTW. the case $k=m$ is here included. When answering your first comment I thought you were already fine with the case $k=m$. My answer and my comments include this case as well.

Comment: @franz3 : Have you tried to write down some examples with numbers to get a feeling how it works? This often helps.

Comment: An important fact which is used here is as follows: if $0 \leq a_1 \leq a_2$ and $0 \leq b_1 \leq b_2 \Rightarrow a_1b_1 \leq a_2b_2$. This is then generalized to: If $0\leq a_1 \leq \cdots \leq a_n$ and $0\leq b_1 \leq \cdots \leq b_n \Rightarrow a_1b_1 \leq a_2b_2 \leq \cdots \leq a_nb_n$.

Comment: Thanks for all your help so far. In your first comment you wrote:$ \frac{\binom nk}{\binom mk} = \frac{n(n-1) \cdots (n-k+1)}{m(m-1) \cdots (m-k+1)}$. But shouldn't it be this: $ \frac{\binom nk}{\binom mk} = \frac{\frac{n!}{k!*(n-k)!}}{\frac{m!}{(m-k)!}}=\frac{n!*k!*(m-k)!}{k!*(n-k)!*m!}=\frac{n!*(m-k)!}{m!*(n-k)!}$

Comment: First of all, the $k!$ is cancelled out. Then, you cancel $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!} = \frac{n\cdot (n-1) \cdots (n-k+1)\cdot \color{blue}{(n-k) \cdots 1}}{\color{blue}{(n-k) \cdots 1}}$. Similarly with $\frac{m!}{(m-k)!}$.

Comment: There are plenty of ways to transform expressions. But here is the question, whether a certain transformation helps you to prove your statement. So, one usually tries certain transformations and if one gets stuck one might try something else. Obviously your last transformation didn't help much in proving your inequality. So, it might be good to try something else. For example, the way I suggested.

Comment: Why do we have to check the cases $k=0$ and $k=m$? At first I did it to see whether I could find or see something. But now, just like you showed, I transformed the entire term until the k-factors were visible and derived from that $\frac{n}{m} \leq \frac{n-i}{m-i}$. I then changed the term into $m \leq n$. So do we have to check the cases?

Comment: You did this. I would have checked the case $k=0$ separately because there aren't any factors $\frac mn$ to be considered. All other cases follow from the formulas given above in the answer and in the comments.